# Django-Rest-Framework: How to Document GET-less Endpoint?

Tags: documentation, django-rest-framework

My co-worker implemented an API that only allows GET requests with an ID parameter (so I can GET `/foo/5` but can't GET `/foo/`).  If I try to access the API's endpoint without providing an ID parameter, it (correctly) throws an unimplemented exception.

I want to fix this endpoint to show its documentation when viewed, without an ID, over the web.  However, I still want it to throw an exception when that endpoint is accessed programatically.

As I remember it, django-rest-framework is capable of distinguishing those two cases (via request headers), but I'm not sure how to define the endpoint such that it returns either documentation HTML or an exception  as appropriate.

Can anyone help provide the pattern for this?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the description, I would guess that the endpoint is a function based view, which is registered on a route where it listens for get requests WITH parameters. I would suggest to register another route where you will listen for get requests without parameters...

```python
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework import status


@api_view(['GET'])
def existing_get_item_api(request, item_id, *args, **kwargs):
    # query and return the item here ...
    pass


@api_view(['GET'])
def get_help(request, *args, **kwargs):
    # compose the help
    return Response(data=help, status = status.HTTP_200_OK)

# somewhere in urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'api/items/(?P<item_id>[0-9]+)/', existing_get_item_api),
    url(r'api/items/', get_help),        
]
```

Let me know how is this working out for you.

Answer (score 1):

We can user [modelviewsets](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset) and [routers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/) for this implementation

## viewsets.py

```
class AccountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    A simple ViewSet for viewing and editing accounts.
    """
    http_method_names = ['GET']
    queryset = Account.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
```

## routers.py

```
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'accounts', AccountViewSet)
```